# Embed a video using multimedia package without any links to external files

Tags: links, multimedia, video

I'm embedding some videos with the multimedia package: after the .pdf is generated, those videos are linked to the file. I was wondering if I can embed them into the .pdf as to transfer just the .pdf file.

Thanks in advance